# Insert iteration data into database

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm using codeigniter.I want to insert data in every iteration to database.

**controller**

```
 $fee=500;
 $trans_fee=300;
 $ins_arr=array(2,3);
 $ins_array_count=count($ins_arr) ; 

 if(!in_array('1', $ins_arr))
 {
   for($i=0;$i<$ins_array_count;$i++)
   {
      $ins.'_'.$ins_arr[$i]= ($fee+$trans_fee);  
       $ins_sum+= $ins_.$ins_arr[$i];

    }

  }
```

i want to get the data inside this variable like( `$ins_2` and `$ins_3`) and insert the value of `$ins_2` and `$ins_3` into db

I got value of  `$ins_sum` correctly

Anyone please answer me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in `{}`:

Using `${}` is a way to create dynamic variables, simple example:

```
${'a' . 'b'} = 'hello there';
echo $ab; // hello there
```

So,

```
$fee = 500;
$trans_fee = 300;
$ins_arr = array(2,3);
$ins_array_count=count($ins_arr) ; 

$ins_sum = 0;
if(!in_array('1', $ins_arr))
{
    for($i=0;$i<$ins_array_count;$i++)
    {
        //$ins_.$ins_arr[$i] = ($fee+$trans_fee); 
        ${"ins_" . $ins_arr[$i]} = ($fee+$trans_fee);       
        $ins_sum += ${"ins_" . $ins_arr[$i]};
    }
}

echo $ins_2; //result of ins_2 = 800
echo "<br />";
echo $ins_3; //result of ins_3 = 800
echo "<br />";
echo $ins_sum; // total ins sum = 1600
```